# React.createElement: type is invalid - expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a simple routing program giving the error as mention in title. Below is my code.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>hello</h2>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

home.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/home';
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

It is printing hello (from app.js)

Comment: Do you have additional error info. What compoennt is udefined?

Comment: its saying child component is undefined. basically i feel its saying home.js is undefined.

Comment: IndexRoute is not a component in react-router v4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this in your main file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './components/home';
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
          <App />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: thanks. its working. but can you comment how this would go if the link become bigger. say like /home/page/something/:someid like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `App` component has no children, so there is no need to try and render them. It basically makes you try to render `undefined`. So basically just remove that line:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>hello</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```